# Change Permissions on macOS USB Device

Tags: macos, usb, permission

I need to find out how to set the permissions of a USB flash drive at the device (not filesystem) level.  In other words, I need to grant the *user* read/write access to a USB device identified by `diskutil` which is `/dev/diskX` where X is some integer.

For example, I insert a USB flash drive and according to `diskutil` it's identifier is `/dev/disk5`.  If I check the permissions of it:

```
$ ls /dev/disk5*
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,  15 May 15 08:35 /dev/disk5
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,  16 May 15 08:35 /dev/disk5s1
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,  17 May 15 08:35 /dev/disk5s2
```

It has `root:operator` ownership and `rw` access limited to root and `r` access to `operators` only (this is why you must issue commands that modify the device as `sudo`).

What I need to do is give `rw` access to the operator as well and it's not as simple as just `chmod 660 /dev/disk5`.  The moment you unplug the device and plug it back in, it loses the permissions.

Why do I need to do this?

I need to boot a USB flash drive in VirtualBox.  To do so, I need to be able to create a "raw" disk image as a passthrough to the actual USB device.  The problem is, to do this, I must issue the command via `sudo` which then changes the user I am executing `VBoxManage` which causes a number of errors since `root` has an environment completely different than the logged in user.

This can be accomplished in FreeBSD (I am sure Linux as well via a different method) by modifying the `devfs.rules` file and adding in a line like:

```
add path 'da*' mode 0660 group operator
```

Which essentially gives `rw` access to any USB storage device (USB storage is identified by FreeBSD as `/dev/da0`, `/dev/da1`, etc.)

How do I do this on macOS?

Comment: You would have to make a persistent autofs mapping I suspect. macOS might store them in the local directory (as in LDAP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to find a way to get direct access to the raw device, however, VirtualBox has a "raw disk access" feature that allowed me to get around this problem.

The way this works is a VMDK drive is created that is actually mapped to a physical volume.  This acts as a passthrough so that VB can access a physical device.

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "</path/to/file>.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/disk#
```

For example, if I had a *physical* USB device with an OS installer I could create a VMDK which I could attach to a VM.

Example:

Assume a USB installer with macOS/FreeBSD/Linux/Windows.  To attach that physical USB to a VM (assuming /dev/disk3 is the USB device),

1. Insert and ***unmount*** (not eject) the device.

   ```
   diskutil unmount /dev/disk3
   ```
2. Create the VMDK

   ```
   sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "USB_OS_Installer.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/disk3
   ```
3. Take ownership of the VMDK (it was created as root via `sudo`; replace "user" with your username and leave the group "staff" as is)

   ```
   sudo chown user:staff USB_OS_Installer.vmdk
   ```
4. Attach the VMDK to the VM in VirtualBox's GUI.

You now have access to a physical boot media device through your VM.