# FTDI USB to serial module doesn't work in Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, driver, kernel, kernel-extensions

I can see FTDI module in system report

[image]

But in arduino it doesn't show up
[image]

I read that macOS comes with USBSerial.kext which can handle this but I don't see it working for me.

I have tried installing FTDI driver and I can see .kext in /system/library/extensions and still doesn't work.

Response from FTDI regarding signed drivers

> Apple are moving from what are called Kernel Extentions (.kexts) to what are called Driver Extensions (.dexts) for the implementation of drivers starting in macOS Catalina (10.15). Currently .kexts are still supported in macOS Catalina, however after the beta release they issued an update which stopped our driver from loading. This update required our driver (FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext) to be re-signed and notarized, we completed this process with an updated Apple Developer ID (as they lapse every two years). Unfortunately when Apple issued our new Developer ID to re-sign and notarize the driver package they did so without the .kext support option enabled (as .kexts are being deprecated it is no longer automatically included). This is why there is a code signature issue with our driver, currently we are waiting on Apple issuing us with the correct Developer ID to be able to sign .kexts for macOS Catalina.
>
> As such our current VCP driver available on the website has a signature issue and wont load. However if the device you are using implements a default FTDI VID/PID combination it should be picked up by the inbuilt AppleUSBFTDI.dext driver and present accordingly in the ‘/dev’ folder on your system in the following form:
>
> /dev/cu.usbserial-xxxxxxxx
>
> /dev/tty.usbserial-xxxxxxxx

**UPDATE**: Module works with High sierra 10.13.6

Comment: If you have an answer to the question, **post it as an answer.**. Please don’t edit the question  with answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the FTDI forum as well and got it to work with their 2.4.4 driver. Keep in mind that only the old 2.4.2 driver is available on their website as of now.