# FTDI Driver 2.4.2

Tags: macos, usb, open-source

I just updated my computer to Mac OS 10.15.5 (Catalina)
Only I can't get my Ired 2 software to work because I have to install FTDI Driver 2.4.2 (64 bits)

So I installed FTDI Driver 2.4.2 but it was not recognized by my computer.
[image]

I want to run [IrTrans Usb](https://www.irtrans.de/en/shop/usb.php) and [Ired2](http://www.tinbert.com/iRed2/gallery)
But when I launch Ired 2 the serial and firmware is not recognized!
Yet the inputs are well recognized in usb
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this question/answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/391256/119271  It seems to be s driver signing issue.

Comment: It looks like the software both installed and is recognized based on your screen shot. Perhaps if you added what you're trying to do, what your results are we won't have to guess at what's next? See [ask] for details on editing.

Comment: [So that’s a great edit! Thank you](https://www.revk.uk/2019/12/ftdi-usb-serial-macos-catalina-resource.html) and +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to contact the developers of the driver, and ask for a version that works on Catalina.

Catalina has introduced security features and changes to the way that third-party kernel extensions are handled.

Comment: Ok I'll contact the developers.
How can I contact Shivam Chauhan so that he gives me version 2.4.4?

Comment: Go to their website and look for Contact info?